# Can not switch language with hotkey keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

I have added the locale language at installation. System is installed freshly and has latest updates.

keyboard language does not switch with keyboard shortcuts (alt + shift).
Can I change the language only through the menu with the mouse.
In the text input options menu, everything is configured correctly

Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04
Language: Russian 
What is the solution?

Comment: Do you want to change language or input source?

Answer (score 0):

check the settings permissions. I found that `~/.config/ibus/bus` owned by root and user can't access it. There should be `IBUS_DEMON_PID` maintained by daemon. So change the owner and restart PC to populate the relationship.